# PHP HTTP build query without array notation

Tags: php, http, parameters, get

For an extern (Django) API we need to pass our GET query data to them as follow:

?`products=Product1&products=Product2`

So as you can see they use different encoding for arrays than the PHP inbuilt

`http_build_query(['Product1', 'Product2'])` => ?`products[]=Product1&products[]=Product2`

Is there a **built in PHP way** to build query to get the result the Django API expects? Or do I have to write something my self?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't know of anything built-in. But you could probably just do a str_replace of `products%5B0%5D` to `product` on the result.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for your reply, but that wouldn't work in a bigger array. This was just a small example. That's why I'm looking for a built in way.

Comment: If you need it for just one "level", then it could still easily be done this way, by looping over the keys. If not - then you're probably best of writing something yourself.

Comment: @CBroe Yeah array in our case is multiple levels deep. Thanks for your reply anyways! :_)

Answer (score 1):

**You can use code below**

```
$params = ['products'=>['Product1', 'Product2']];
$query_params = http_build_query($params,null, '&');
$query_string = preg_replace('/%5B(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]+)%5D=/', '=', $query_params);
print_r($query_string);
```

This will get query string like **"products=Product1&products=Product2"**

Comment: Thanks, I upvoted your comment, I like the approach. But it is not really what I asked for, since it is more levels deep. And asked for an inbuilt solution.

Comment: I am facing same challenge previously but not found any build in function to do that , so used above code  @JelmerdeVries

Answer (score 0):

That format is not supported natively.

I think the main reason is that URL parameters are a flat key/value structure, while `http_build_query()` can serialise arbitrarily nested arrays and objects. To support that, you need some convention to handle data trees in a flat list. URL specs don't provide any. PHP uses the `[]` notation to mimic arrays elsewhere (e.g. `$_GET`), so it makes sense to have such convention in the builtin query creation function.

If you are not going to need nested data, you can easily write your own function:

```
function encodeParams(array $data): string
{
    $params = [];
    foreach ($data as $name => $val) {
        if (is_array($val)) {
            foreach ($val as $v) {
                $params[] = sprintf('%s=%s', rawurldecode($name), rawurldecode($v));
            }
        } else {
            $params[] = sprintf('%s=%s', rawurldecode($name), rawurldecode($val));
        }
    }
    return implode('&', $params);
}

$test = [
    'products' => [
        'Product1',
        'Product2',
    ],
    'page' => 123,
    'order' => 'asc'
];

var_dump(http_build_query($test));
var_dump(encodeParams($test));
```

```
string(68) "products%5B0%5D=Product1&products%5B1%5D=Product2&page=123&order=asc"
string(54) "products=Product1&products=Product2&page=123&order=asc"
```

If you'll need nested data after all, you first have to decide what your naming convention would be.